# QGraphicsItems not showing up QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I'm trying to build a custom widget with a QGraphicsScene inside it.

```
class Graphics:public QWidget{
  public:
 Graphis();
}

Graphics::Graphics(){
 QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    
    
    QGridLayout* grid = new QGridLayout;

    
    
    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    
    
    QGraphicsLineItem* y = new QGraphicsLineItem(scene->width()/2, 0, scene->width() / 2, scene->height());
    QGraphicsLineItem* x = new QGraphicsLineItem(0, scene->height() / 2, scene->width(), scene->height() / 2);
    scene->addItem(y);
    scene->addItem(x);
    
    

    grid->addWidget(view, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    setLayout(grid);

    view->setScene(scene);
    view->show();
}
```

But when I run the widget, only an empty scene shows up in the QGraphicsView widget inside the main widget.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Same results. I think it's just a syntactic change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this instead; I think one problem is that `scene->width()` and `scene->height()` are very likely both returning 0, at least on your first call to them, since `sceneRect()` defaults to returning a QRect big enough to fit the current contents of the scene (which is initially empty):

```
Graphics::Graphics(){
    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    QGridLayout* grid = new QGridLayout(this);
    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(scene, this);

    scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    QGraphicsLineItem* y = new QGraphicsLineItem(scene->width()/2, 0, scene->width() / 2, scene->height());
    QGraphicsLineItem* x = new QGraphicsLineItem(0, scene->height() / 2, scene->width(), scene->height() / 2);
    scene->addItem(y);
    scene->addItem(x);

    grid->addWidget(view, 0, 0, 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: That works! Is there any way to set the size of the QGraphicsScene equal to the device's monitor size?

Comment: Try QDesktopWidget::screenGeometry(view) to get the monitor's QRect https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html#screenGeometry-1